# В чем проблема кода?

Tags: python, telebot

Хотел добавить стикер в телеграм бота, а получается такая вот проблемка

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В питоне одиночный слэш используется в качестве экранирования, для указания полного пути вам подойдут следующие варианты:

```py
file = open('D:\\Folder\\Folder1\\','rb')
```

или так, литерал `r` в данном случае отключает экранирование.

```py
file = open(r'D:\Folder\Folder1\','rb')
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавь букву `r` перед первым апострофом.